# How to make vim automatically do a CTRL+D after jumping to a tag?

Tags: cursor-movement, tags

When I use `CTRL+]` to jump to a tag, the cursor will be placed at the center of the window. How can I make it stop at the top of the window? Now I do this by pressing `CTRL+D` after each jump. I was wondering whether vim can do this for me automatically.

Comment: You can remap everything; e.g. `:nnoremap <C-]> <C-]><C-d>`. But Vim should already put the cursor at the top of the screen with just `<C-]>`. [it does for me, anyway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts2wp.png). Which filetype are you using? Make use a custom implementation. Also see: [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Oh I didn't realize this, but vim does place the cursor at the top when jumping in help files. The filetype I'm using is C++.

Comment: `vim does place the cursor at the top` but your question says `the cursor will be placed at the center`?

Comment: Yeah the behaviours are different in help files and C++ files.

Comment: Note that `<C-d>` will leave the cursor where it is in the window, but scroll the buffer, so the cursor will no longer be on the tag. `zt` (and related commands `zz` and `zb`) will move the cursor and buffer together, so both will be at the top (or middle or bottom) of the window.